# Why is traceid sent in automatic 400 responses in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

ASP.NET Core 2.2 sends [automatic 400 responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#automatic-http-400-responses) for actions which fail model binding and validation.

The result looks like:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "xyz:xyz"
}
```

What is `traceId`, and why is it sent to the client?

Comment: The trace id should be the value of `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` which is used to uniquely identify the request in things like logs. In short, you should be able to look up the value of `traceId` in your logs to potentially find out more information about why it was a "bad request". That of course assumes that you're logging at all and logging well, and it's also only of benefit to you as a developer and not the end-client. But they can share that with you if you're handling a trouble ticket, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From @ChrisPratt's comment above:

> The trace id should be the value of `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` which is used to uniquely identify the request in things like logs. In short, you should be able to look up the value of `traceId` in your logs to potentially find out more information about why it was a "bad request". That of course assumes that you're logging at all and logging well, and it's also only of benefit to you as a developer and not the end-client. But they can share that with you if you're handling a trouble ticket, for example.